# Fastest way to find the abciss of the barycenter of a given trapezoid

Tags: geometry, barycentric-coordinates

I'm a student programmer and I need, given a trapeze of height 1 and given the abcisses of its vertices, to find the abcisse of its barycenter.
How can I do this the fastest way ?

Thank you

Comment: $(A_x+B_x+C_x+D_x)/4$ (arithmetic mean of vertices abscissae).

Comment: Take care : in 2D, you have 3 kinds of barycenters : the barycenter of vertices (as Aretino has shown), the barycenter of (uniformely weighted sides and the surface barycenter ; in general, all of them are different.